# How to get a random seed value at that randomize simulation time in SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I know 3 EDA companies handle with SVSEED as the below image,
[image]
For reproducibility and random stability, I'd like to generate a random value by using "+svseed random" in SystemVerilog Cadence simulation as the below example snippet code,

```
class const_c;
rand bit [7:0] a;
...
endclass


module test;
...
const_c cons;
cons = new();


initial begin

    for(...) begin
       cons.randomize();
       printf("Current SVSEED: %0d", ?);
    end

end
endmodule
```

How do we know "svseed" value when "-svseed random" used. it's value in SystemVerilog?

Comment: For a simulation run you can pass svseed as an argument to the tool. Which tool you use?

Comment: @MituRaj Cadence Xcelium, how do I get that value?

Comment: If you used svseed flag, the value of seed should be the simulation log file. The default is value is 1 in some tools if you don't mention to the simulator.

Comment: Is that only available in the simulation log file to get the value? because I'd like to make a directory each simulation by SVSEED value. and If I can get a SVSEED value in simulation time, it will be handy.

Comment: Are you using svseed random?

Comment: @MituRaj Yes. I am using svseed random

Comment: I normally use svseed (random number), where this random number is generated by a Linux shell and passed as argument to the simulation command to the tool. In this way I know which root seed was used for the run.  Not sure whether we can access this seed value anywhere inside SV modules, cz they use derived seeds.

Comment: FYI, you have VCS and Questa switches swapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, at least there is no direct method to find the root seed set by the simulator ahead of the simulation run. The value set by `sv_seed` flag is usually found in the log generated by the simulation. If not used, it's defaulted to 1 in some tools.

> Because I'd like to make a directory each simulation by SVSEED value. and If I can get a SVSEED value in simulation time, it will be handy.

A work-around I have done in Questa-Sim in the past is generating a random root seed \$ R \$ in a script/makefile, and then create necessary simulation folders corresponding to this generated seed. Finally, invoke the simulation command from the script, and pass \$R\$  as argument using `-sv_seed R` flag.